# How to avoid double slash in Github repo URL?

Tags: github, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create AWS Codepipeline webhook with tag filter and plug it to existing repository webhook via terraform in accordance with [Terraform docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/codepipeline_webhook)

Code which I've used:

```
resource "aws_codepipeline_webhook" "pprod_webhook" {
  name            = "${var.client_code}-${var.environment}-pprod-hook"
  authentication  = "GITHUB_HMAC"
  target_action   = "Source"
  target_pipeline = aws_codepipeline.cd.name

  authentication_configuration {
    secret_token = data.aws_ssm_parameter.github_token.value
  }

  filter {
    json_path    = "$.ref_type"
    match_equals = "tag"
  }
}

resource "github_repository_webhook" "github_hook" {
  repository = "org_name/repo_name"

  configuration {
    url          = aws_codepipeline_webhook.pprod_webhook.url
    content_type = "json"
    insecure_ssl = false
    secret       = data.aws_ssm_parameter.webhook_secret.value
  }

  active = true
  events = ["create"]
}
```

EDIT `terraform plan`:

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create
  ~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

 # module.codepipeline.github_repository_webhook.github_hook will be created
  + resource "github_repository_webhook" "github_hook" {
      + active     = true
      + etag       = (known after apply)
      + events     = [
          + "create",
        ]
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + repository = "org_name/repo_name"
      + url        = (known after apply)

      + configuration {
          + content_type = "json"
          + insecure_ssl = false
          + secret       = (sensitive value)
          + url          = (sensitive value)
        }
    }
```

EDIT with `gh_url` output from terraform: I'm getting payload url which is in Github. Seems I do not have to create Github webhook, since one is in place already, but don't know if creating filter only will allow me trigger pipeline from tags only

Unfortunately I'm getting error:

> Error: POST https://api.github.com/repos//org_name/repo_name/hooks:
> 404 Not Found []

No idea why I'm getting `//` in above URL. Is there any one who knows how to make that work?

Comment: Would you mind posting the other part of `terraform plan`, maybe there's something there?

Comment: I've added rest of the plan.

Comment: Thanks, but I was referring to the output of `terraform plan` command. You can of course omit the secrets if they are visible.

Comment: Or, you could alternatively do local debugging. Add this before the `github_repository_webhook`: ```output "gh_url" {
  value = aws_codepipeline_webhook.pprod_webhook.url
}``` and run `terraform output gh_url`.

Comment: Yes sure always forgetting about outputs, will do

Comment: Error appears only afer `terraform apply`, `terraform plan` output looks ok. Adding output as you mentioned generates no output - `Warning: No outputs found`

Comment: Are you sure the double `/` is the actual reason for the error?
Couldn't it be the credentials not being "enough" for the private project in question?

Comment: Honestly don't know anymore. Secret in Github and one from parameter store are the same, just checked. Just terraform is throwing error and there is this double `/` which is not existing in any payload from Github. Maybe you know other way how to trigger AWS Codepipeline once tag is being pushed to repository... ?

Comment: Hm, and is the CodePipeline resource visible in AWS console? If there's no output, I suspect it might not be created. Does it fail at the webhook step or before that?

Comment: Take a look in updated question, I've got output, plus some additional information.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, was quick to reply without paying attention. Does the payload URL contain the `ref_type` and `tag`? In that case, my best guess would be it will be triggered. But I guess you would have to test it, not sure otherwise. :)

Comment: So basically it was not working :(. What I did, is that I've used Codebuild project to initialize Codepipeline and I have deactivated pipeline webhook. Pitty that Codepipeline do not have the same posibilities like COdebuild but o well we have MacOs in EC2 now...

Answer (score 3):

You're missing configuring github provider

```
provider "github" {
  token = "secret"
  owner = "owner"
}
```

Also for the repository, you just have to specify the project

```
resource "github_repository_webhook" "github_hook" {
  repository = "repo_name"
...
}
```